# Get the length of scene in driver expression

Tags: python, drivers

Is it possible to get the length of the current scene in a driver?

I'm trying to make properties loop, without having to edit the drivers if I change the first or last frame. I'm coming from an After Effects background, so what I want is something equivalent to AE expression's `thisComp.duration`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just paste this into your driver's field:

```
bpy.context.scene.frame_end - bpy.context.scene.frame_start
```

i put it in my x-scale:

[image]

Note: works only if your animation is playing.